# ¿Como hago que el bot de discord mande el resultado de una funcion?

Tags: discord.py, bot

Quiero crear un comando para que el bot remplace una palabra y la traduzca a código morse mediante $morse "palabra". El problema que me surge es que a la hora de introducir el comando, manda al discord "<coroutine object convert_to_morse at 0x00000219D187DF20>" y agradecería que me dieran una idea del por qué sucede.
También agradecería si me dieran una pequeña idea de como reutilizar los mensajes, porque estoy seguro que debe haber un código mucho mejor del que use para trasladarlo a morse
Disculpen si es muy largo el código para algo simple, soy nuevo en esto de Python

````
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    
    if message.content.startswith('$morse'):
        await message.channel.send(convert_to_morse(code=message.content))   

@client.event
async def convert_to_morse(code):
code = on_message()
code = code.replace("a", " .-")
code = code.replace("A", " .-")
code = code.replace("á", " .-")
code = code.replace("Á", " .-")
code = code.replace("s", " ...")
code = code.replace("S", " ...")
code = code.replace("t", " -")
code = code.replace("T", " -")
code = code.replace("u", " ..-")
code = code.replace("U", " ..-")
code = code.replace("ú", " ..-")
code = code.replace("Ú", " ..-")
code = code.replace("v", " ...-")
code = code.replace("V", " ...-")
code = code.replace("w", " .--")
code = code.replace("W", " .--")
code = code.replace("x", " -..-")
code = code.replace("X", " -..-")
code = code.replace("y", " -.--")
code = code.replace("Y", " -.--")
code = code.replace("z", " --..")
code = code.replace("Z", " --..")
code = code.replace("b", " -...")
code = code.replace("B", " -...")
code = code.replace("c", " -.-.")
code = code.replace("C", " -.-.")
code = code.replace("d", " -..")
code = code.replace("D", " -..")
code = code.replace("e", " .")
code = code.replace("E", " .")
code = code.replace("f", " ..-.")
code = code.replace("F", " ..-.")
code = code.replace("g", " --.")
code = code.replace("G", " --.")
code = code.replace("h", " ....")
code = code.replace("h", " ....")
code = code.replace("H", " ....")
code = code.replace("i", " ..")
code = code.replace("I", " ..")
code = code.replace("í", " ..")
code = code.replace("Í", " ..")
code = code.replace("j", " .---")
code = code.replace("J", " .---")
code = code.replace("k", " -.-")
code = code.replace("K", " -.-")
code = code.replace("l", " .-..")
code = code.replace("L", " .-..")
code = code.replace("m", " --")
code = code.replace("M", " --")
code = code.replace("r", " .-.")
code = code.replace("R", " .-.")
code = code.replace("q", " --.-")
code = code.replace("Q", " --.-")
code = code.replace("n", " -.")
code = code.replace("N", " -.")
code = code.replace("o", " ---")
code = code.replace("O", " ---")
code = code.replace("p", " .--.")
code = code.replace("P", " .--.")
return code

client.run('token')```
````

Comment: Creo que el problema ronda cerca a esta línea: `code = on_message()` en `async def convert_to_morse(code)`. Sabiendo que `on_message` es un evento del bot y encima no devuelve nada.

Comment: Elimina de la función `convert_to_morse(code)` el decorador `@client.event`, el `async`  y la primera línea (`code = on_message()`). Con eso ya lo tienes funcional. En cuánto a la conversión a morse, posibles mejoras serían utilizar un diccionario con claves las letras y valor su respectiva traducción a morse. También dado que según tu código las mayúsculas y minúsculas se leen igual, podrías convertir el contenido del mensaje a minúsculas y así te ahorras la mitad de las claves